# spark read wholeTextFiles with non UTF-8 encoding

Tags: apache-spark, character-encoding, apache-spark-sql

I want to read whole text files in non UTF-8 encoding via

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(path, 12).toDF
```

into spark. How can I change the encoding?
I would want to read ISO-8859 encoded text, but it is not CSV, it is something similar to xml:SGML.

## edit

maybe a custom Hadoop file input format should be used?

- https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-hadoops-input-format-and-output-forma
- http://henning.kropponline.de/2016/10/23/custom-matlab-inputformat-for-apache-spark/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Simple.

Here is the source code,

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset

import org.apache.hadoop.io.{Text, LongWritable}
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object TextFile {
  val DEFAULT_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8")

  def withCharset(context: SparkContext, location: String, charset: String): RDD[String] = {
    if (Charset.forName(charset) == DEFAULT_CHARSET) {
      context.textFile(location)
    } else {
      // can't pass a Charset object here cause its not serializable
      // TODO: maybe use mapPartitions instead?
      context.hadoopFile[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](location).map(
        pair => new String(pair._2.getBytes, 0, pair._2.getLength, charset)
      )
    }
  }
}
```

From here it's copied.

https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/util/TextFile.scala

To Use it.

https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/util/TextFileSuite.scala

**Edit:**

If you need wholetext file,

Here is the actual source of the implementation.

```
def wholeTextFiles(
      path: String,
      minPartitions: Int = defaultMinPartitions): RDD[(String, String)] = withScope {
    assertNotStopped()
    val job = NewHadoopJob.getInstance(hadoopConfiguration)
    // Use setInputPaths so that wholeTextFiles aligns with hadoopFile/textFile in taking
    // comma separated files as input. (see SPARK-7155)
    NewFileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, path)
    val updateConf = job.getConfiguration
    new WholeTextFileRDD(
      this,
      classOf[WholeTextFileInputFormat],
      classOf[Text],
      classOf[Text],
      updateConf,
      minPartitions).map(record => (record._1.toString, record._2.toString)).setName(path)
  }
```

Try changing :

```
.map(record => (record._1.toString, record._2.toString))
```

to(probably):

```
.map(record => (record._1.toString, new String(record._2.getBytes, 0, record._2.getLength, "myCustomCharset")))
```

Comment: That does seem to be a good start. But How can I achieve similar behavior of wholeTextFiles where the file path is contained as a key and a single row will be created per file unlike the spark-csv variant above, where the lines in a file will be tokenized into rows in the RDD.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L870

Comment: I think this is nearly there. But `.map(record => (record._1.toString, record._2.toString, "iso-8859-1")).setName(path)` will fail to compile due to `found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, String)]
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)]
`

Comment: And I am not sure if `WholeTextFileInputFormat` wouldn't need to be redefined using the desired encoding?

Comment: Would I be required to replace `RecordReader[Text, Text]` with a custom `Text`implementation which is not using `UTF-8`?

Answer (score 8):

You can read the files using `SparkContext.binaryFiles()` instead and build the `String` for the contents specifying the charset you need. E.g:

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles(path, 12)
  .mapValues(content => new String(content.toArray(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))
  .toDF
```

Comment: See now, this is simple!