# Special character as file delimiter in spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have text file with special delimiter:

```
35¡1682¡231¡20.00000000¡50.00000000¡0.00000000¡0.00000000¡304.1100¡333.110000
¡I¡1¡0¡10¡SHORT NAME
1105682¡0¡100000.00000000¡100000.00000000¡1105682¡D¡D
```

I want to split this file in spark based on special delimiter present `¡`.
Please suggest workaround.
And Output of this command is coming as

```
val input_header = sc.textFile(path).first()
```

[image: Out of sc.textfile]

When I am reading this file in RDD and displaying content of it. Its showing delimiter as `?`

Comment: Have you checked the UTF encoding of your file?

Comment: You should probable check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43200978/spark-read-wholetextfiles-with-non-utf-8-encoding

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file as collection bits and bits to string providing encoding.
If you using scala API it would be something like this

```
val inputHeader = sc.binaryFiles(path).mapValues(line => new String(line.toArray(), StandardCharsets.{your charset})
```

You can then ensure that Spark have read your file correctly with

```
inputHeader.first
```

Comment: Here, where we have specified delimiter.? And my platform is Unix so character set would be UTF_8 right?

Comment: import java.nio.charset._
val input_header = sc.binaryFiles("hdfs:///user/pandvini_adm/B%52%41IN%53D%41ILY_BW_a12_NT%46_rnv_20160514_20160520121442.dat").
mapValues(line => new String((line.toArray(),"utf-8")))
But getting error like 
<console>:31: error: overloaded method constructor String with alternatives:
  (x$1: StringBuilder)String <and>
  (x$1: StringBuffer)String <and>
  (x$1: Array[Byte])String <and>
  (x$1: Array[Char])String <and>
  (x$1: String)String
 cannot be applied to ((Array[Byte], String))
       mapValues(line => new String((line.toArray(),"utf-8")))

Comment: You shouldn't use string like "utf-8".
You should use one of defined charsets, like StandardCharsets.UTF_8.
Or you may use Charset.forName("utf-8")

Comment: @vinitkumar : if you are okay consider accepting answer. it wiil be pointer to other users as well. if not comment with you questions.